# How to uninstall google chrome using registry in windows system?

Tags: windows, registry

I have seen that by deleting the **`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Google Chrome`**
folder we can Uninstall Google chrome. But in my computer I don't have Google Chrome folder.

Comment: Deleting this registry key does not really uninstall the software. It just removes the entry under "Programs and Features", but the software keeps being installed, meaning all files and any additional registry keys that have been created by the installer, will still be there.

Comment: Can't we uninstall from registry?then